# Turtle onscreenclick not behaving as expected

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a basic Turtle Race. My only requirement is that the turtles must move with each click on the screen. I am trying to use onscreenclick to call a function that moves the turtles forward a random amount and then checks their x-coordinates to determine if someone has won.

```
import turtle
import random
import time

def raceRound():
    firstRacer.forward(random.randint(1, 10))
    secondRacer.forward(random.randint(1, 10))
    checkWinner()


def firstRacerSetup():
    # setup turtle

def secondRacerSetup():
    # set up second turtle

def screenSetup():
    # create screen
def checkWinner():
    if firstRacer.xcor() >= 80:
        announcer.write("Congratualtions! You won!")
    if secondRacer.xcor() >= 80:
        announcer.write("Sorry... You lost")

wn = turtle.Screen()
racerName = wn.textinput("Name Entry", "What would you like your turtle's name to be?")
screenSetup()

announcer = turtle.Turtle()
announcer.hideturtle()
announcer.penup()
announcer.goto(0, -140)
announcer.write("Welcome to the race!", align='center')
time.sleep(3)

firstRacerSetup()
secondRacerSetup()
announcer.write("Click to start the race!", align='center')

wn.onscreenclick(raceRound)
turtle.done()
```

I'm just not sure where I am going wrong and some assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the output/error you are getting? Do you have output from your code? Also, your `def screenSetup():` method is empty, that's not correct syntax in python.

Comment: Your code calls `raceRound()` a grand total of one time, and sets the click handling function to be the value it returns (which is `None`, since the function doesn't explicitly return anything).  You want `wn.onscreenclick(raceRound)` - note the lack of parentheses which would indicate an immediate call to `raceRound`.

Comment: I click and nothing happens... The screenSetup function is 30 lines just drawing the racetrack so I didn't include it.

Comment: @jasonharper When I remove the parentheses, I get the following error upon clicking:
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\turtle.py", line 675, in eventfun
    fun(x, y)
TypeError: raceRound() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`

Comment: Well, the click function receives parameters indicating where the mouse was clicked.  You need to declare the function to accept those parameters, even if you don't use them.

Comment: @jasonharper That did it! Thank You!